# ClipData is sometimes Null in Android

Tags: clipboardmanager

I encountered a strange "problem" or maybe a "bug" in Android.
I use the ClipboardManager for my App quite often.
But if I use it within some seconds twice, I always get a NullPointerException.
What I think is that I Clipboard is notalready filled when I am accessing it but this seems to be a really silly idea...
Has anyone encountered the same problem, or am I doing something wrong?
I get the error at String text = item.getText().toString();

Error message:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at at.co.netconsulting.leotranslater.SettingsActivity$1$3.onPrimaryClipChanged

Thanks for every hint or help in advance!

Here is a piece of my code:

```
final ClipboardManager myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    myClipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                            ClipData cp = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
                            if(cp.getItemCount()>0) {
                                ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0);
                                if (item == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    if(item!=null) {
                                        String text = item.getText().toString();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sie suchen nach dem Wort: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ServiceTranslator.class);
                                        msgIntent.putExtra("ClipBoardData", text);
                                        startService(msgIntent);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the solution.

```
String text = item.coerceToText(getBaseContext()).toString();
```

Looking into the documentation, it is said that 
if all you want is the textual representation of the clipped data, you
 * can use the convenience method {@link Item#coerceToText Item.coerceToText}.

I hope that will solve my problem!